# I need to return Arabic/French month name out of Date object

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I am working on an application and I need to return Arabic/French month name and day name, depending on the local I am using. 
For example, if the local is "Ar" i need the month to be فبراير for February. If local is "Fr" month name should be Février.
I am currently working around it and reading the month and day names from different .properties files.
Now, my question is: is there any way to return month and day names in different languages depending on the given local?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you do not have to work around it. Use `SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)`. Here is the code example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat fen = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy", new Locale("en"));
    SimpleDateFormat ffr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy", new Locale("fr"));

    Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println(fen.format(date));
    System.out.println(ffr.format(date));
```

Comment: Thank you guys, both solutions work really fine. Still numbers are returned in English, like 1,2,3. Is there any way that I can return it depending on the local like ١,٢,٣,٤??

Comment: Arabic numbers are probably separate story. First try SimpleNumberFormat. But I do not believe it will help. I had some experience with parsing of Arabic numbers and just wrote my own parser that substitute Arabic digits by their European analogues.

Answer (score 4):

Formatter is the most flexible variant. There are convenience methods, like String.format() and printf() that is using Formatter too.

```
Date d = new Date();

Locale saudi = new Locale("ar","SA");

Formatter formatter = new Formatter(System.out,Locale.FRENCH);
formatter.format("month: %tB\n", d);
System.out.printf(saudi, "month: %tB\n", d);
```

month: décembre
month: ديسمبر

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getMonths` and `getWeekdays` methods of [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) class

```
String getMonthName(int month, Locale locale) {
    return DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale).getMonths()[month];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one method:pass the value of format in which format you will pass month name parameter like "MMM" for JAN.

```
public static String GetMonthInArabic(Context ctx, String month, String format)
{
    String Mon = month;
    try {
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("eng")).parse(Mon);
        Mon = new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("ar")).format(convertedDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Mon;
}
```